# Spring data entities in different packages

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring and want to use the following project structure in spring boot application.

1. Different package for each type of entity and its corresponding repository implementation.
2. A Package for repository configuration

*

```
**com.demo.Customer**
    Customer.java
    CustomerRepository.java
    Application.java

**com.demo.Order**
    Order.java
    OrderRepository.java

**com.demo.config**
    ApplicationConfig.java
    CustomerConfig.java
    OrderConfig.java
```

**CustomerConfig.java**

```
import com.demo.cstore.core.Customer;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Customer.class)
public class CustomerConfiguration {

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.order"}) //inject repository from other packages
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
```

After compiling and running the application, only customer entity is created. Is that because application file just recognizes customer entity as it exists in the same package **com.demo.Customer**. How can Order entity be injected and and an entity is created?

Answer (score 0):

The `EnableJpaRepositories` annotation accepts an array of Strings `basePackages` here you can add all packages where your entities are:

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.demo.order"
,"com.demo.customer"
,"com.demo.config"})
```

That must be enough. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use **@ComponentScan**.
According to documentation

> The @SpringBootApplication annotation is equivalent to using
>   @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan with their
>   default attributes

so you can just use **@SpringBootApplication** on your main class which is located in the base package of your packages hierarchy and you will be fine.

you can too refer to this link to know about how to structure your code and main class location

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

and this the API documentation for **@SpringBootApplication**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html

Comment: welome..please accept it as answer by clicking the green right mark to be marked as answered question for any one who would have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we customize `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, so had to set the packages to scan there eg.:

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.multitenancy.test.entity");
```