# Remove javax.persistence as duplicate dependency in two part spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

In relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76268254/does-it-matter-if-an-entity-for-a-jpa-repository-is-defined-in-another-gradle-pr) question, I have encountered a problem.

I have two projects, a `authlib` and a `server`. `server` is a spring boot 2.4.4 project with java, and `authlib` is a Kotlin project meant to be used as a library to facilitate web requests to the `server`.

I decided to move the entity classes from the `server` to the `authlib`, so I could use them directly when handling the web requests and didn't have to define basically duplicate classes. I use `javax.persistence` for the entity definitions and stuff, so I added the dependency to the build.gradle.kts of the authlib:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.18")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api
    implementation("javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2")
}
```

The `server` uses the `authlib` project like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":authlib"))

    implementation("net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.12")
    implementation("com.github.theholywaffle:teamspeak3-api:1.3.0")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.jboss.aerogear:aerogear-otp-java:1.0.0")
    implementation("org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4")
    implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.5.7")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
    //implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.32.1")
    //implementation("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.32.1")
    //implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev20210811-1.32.1")

    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")


    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")
    testImplementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    testImplementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
}
```

This seemed all fine and dandy to me, except for the fact I had to provide a version number to the `javax.persistence` in the authlib. I thought this would be handled automatically, but oh well. I then built the project and ran it, and it indeed gave me a version conflict:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:88)

The following method did not exist:
    javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

The method's class, javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/persistence-api-1.0.2.jar!/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.class
    jar:file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar!/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo: file:/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
```

I understand that the problem lies in me basically including two different versions of the persistence api in my server project. However, I do not know how to fix this. Do I have to remove the dependency `javax.persistence` from my `implementation(project(":authlib"))`? Or is there some other way to prevent this from happening?

EDIT:

I decided to try to include the exact version of the jakarta.persistence api in my `authlib` and that did something. However, the error indicates that the problem is unchanged and the persistence api is still present twice:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
 with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa
/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested 
exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on 
net.xxx.auth.entity.UserSession.user references an unknown entity: 
net.xxx.authlib.entity.User
```

Comment: You changed your package structure as well, which is not covered by Spring Boot and thus it isn't detecting the entities anymore.

Comment: Adding an annotation to include the package in the search path fron https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539508/spring-data-entities-in-different-packages did not help. I think I still have to remove the duplicate dependency

Comment: If it is the same you don't need to remove it. I would suggest to make it compile only instead of implementation.